# Animate dashed svg on background image

Tags: html, css, animation, svg, polygon

I have a task that looks like this:

[image: part of psd]

I need to animate(draw) this dashed line on background image ( or just `<img />`  - doesn't matter). I used to do such an animation using SVG `path`,  `stroke-dasharray` and  `stroke-dashoffset` by creating ***2 `<path />` - First is solid and Second is dashed ***.

But in this case second `path` need to have same color as background which in my case obviously is not gonna happen because of image.

I made [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L0u6ofrs/) to demonstrate what I have at the moment.

My question though: Is it even possible to achieve this type of animation above some image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've continued to think about this, and finally the solution came to me: simply use a mask, not a clipPath:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg width="575" height="115"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" onload="startAnimation()">
<defs>
  <path id="dashed" d="m14,112c21,-11 35,-14 35,-14c0,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 22,0 23,0c1,0 29,5 29,5c0,0 17,6 17,6c0,0 16,-2 17,-2c1,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 17,-3 17,-3c0,0 13,-3 13,-3c0,0 15,-9 15,-9c0,0 25,-10 25,-10c0,0 24,-2 24,-2c0,0 16,-3 17,-3c1,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 18,0 19,0c1,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 13,-2 14,-2c1,0 14,-8 15,-8c1,0 17,-7 17,-7c0,0 6,-1 7,-2c1,-1 11,-3 11,-3c0,0 21,-2 22,-2c1,0 20,-5 22,-6c2,-1 11,-8 12,-9c1,-1 17,-13 18,-13c1,0 16,-17 17,-18" />
  <mask id="mask">
    <use xlink:href="#dashed" stroke-width="6" stroke="white" stroke-dasharray="1000,0" fill="none">
      <animate id="reveal" attributeType="CSS" attributeName="stroke-dasharray" 
         from="0,1000" to="1000,0" begin="indefinite" dur="5s" fill="freeze" />
    </use>
  </mask>
  <script type="application/ecmascript"><![CDATA[
function startAnimation() {
    var len = document.getElementById('dashed').getTotalLength();
    var animate = document.getElementById('reveal');
    animate.setAttribute('from', '0,' + len);
    animate.setAttribute('to', len + ',0');
    animate.beginElement();
}
  ]]></script>
</defs>
  <use xlink:href="#dashed" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="10" stroke="#E8511B" fill="none" mask="url(#mask)"/>
</svg>
```

As another optimization, and inspired by this d3 [Stroke Dash Interpolation](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5649592), I've computed the path length and animated both values of the `stroke-dasharray` attribute, thus maintaning a constant length of dash + gap.

Comment: oh... it's working!!! Although, don't really know how it works, because I've never used ``mask``. If you have a minute to explain I will really appreciate it.

Comment: The content of `<mask>` is virtually painted (which means, the stroke with its width gets evaluated), and then for every pixel the color average gets added to the alpha channel of the masked element. Meaning, white is translated to opaque, black or nothing is translated to transparent.

Answer (score 0):

For a curved path this is tricky. As long as the line has a dominant direction, you can overlay the path with a cliping rectangle, a bit like opening a curtain on a previously hidden image:

```html
<svg width="575" height="115"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<defs>
  <clipPath id="curtain">
    <rect height="115" width="0">
      <animate attributeType="XML" attributeName="width" 
         from="0" to="575" dur="10s" fill="freeze" />
    </rect>
  </clipPath>
</defs>
<path id="dashed" d="m14,112c21,-11 35,-14 35,-14c0,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 22,0 23,0c1,0 29,5 29,5c0,0 17,6 17,6c0,0 16,-2 17,-2c1,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 17,-3 17,-3c0,0 13,-3 13,-3c0,0 15,-9 15,-9c0,0 25,-10 25,-10c0,0 24,-2 24,-2c0,0 16,-3 17,-3c1,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 18,0 19,0c1,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 13,-2 14,-2c1,0 14,-8 15,-8c1,0 17,-7 17,-7c0,0 6,-1 7,-2c1,-1 11,-3 11,-3c0,0 21,-2 22,-2c1,0 20,-5 22,-6c2,-1 11,-8 12,-9c1,-1 17,-13 18,-13c1,0 16,-17 17,-18" stroke-width="4" stroke-dasharray="10" stroke="#E8511B" fill="none" clip-path="url(#curtain)"/>
</svg>
```

The same could be achieved on the HTML side with css:

```css
#content {
  width: 700px;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
}
#curtain {
    position: relative;
    width: 0%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    animation-name: draw;
    animation-duration: 10s;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; // Stay on the last frame
    animation-iteration-count: 1; // Run only once
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
svg {
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
#dashed {
    stroke-dasharray: 10;
    stroke: #E8511B;
    stroke-width: 4;
    fill: none;
}

@keyframes draw {
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div id="curtain">
    <svg width="575" height="115"  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <path id="dashed" d="m14,112c21,-11 35,-14 35,-14c0,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 22,0 23,0c1,0 29,5 29,5c0,0 17,6 17,6c0,0 16,-2 17,-2c1,0 14,-1 14,-1c0,0 17,-3 17,-3c0,0 13,-3 13,-3c0,0 15,-9 15,-9c0,0 25,-10 25,-10c0,0 24,-2 24,-2c0,0 16,-3 17,-3c1,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 18,0 19,0c1,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,0 21,0c0,0 21,-1 21,-1c0,0 13,-2 14,-2c1,0 14,-8 15,-8c1,0 17,-7 17,-7c0,0 6,-1 7,-2c1,-1 11,-3 11,-3c0,0 21,-2 22,-2c1,0 20,-5 22,-6c2,-1 11,-8 12,-9c1,-1 17,-13 18,-13c1,0 16,-17 17,-18" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <img src="" class="img">
</div>
```

Ovviously, this does not result in a steady pace "along the path". I am not aware how to achieve this with a curved path (exept some very special cases where the "leading" point can be expressed in a mathematically simple function of time).

Comment: yes it works, but as you pointed only with not really curvy lines. I have couple of lines like [this](http://storage8.static.itmages.com/i/17/0513/h_1494664919_2015816_6923380360.png) . This trick with curtain won't work in this case.